# error "There is already an object named 'MD' in the database."

Tags: c#, database

connection string config file

```html
<connectionStrings>
     <addname="cs1"connectionString="DataSource=SUKKOORPC\SQLEXPRESSPersistSecurityInfo=True;User ID=sa;Password=admin123"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

i am create class file.below code,

```cs
public class Co
{
    public static SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    public static string str;

    public static void connectDB()
    {
        if (Co.con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            Co.str = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs1"].ToString();
            Co.con.ConnectionString = Co.str;
            Co.con.Open();
         }
     }
}
```

access the execute query using class file in form2 .

```cs
SqlCommand sc2 = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE IT(Name nchar(50),Phoneno int,Doorno nchar(50),Streetname nchar(50),City nchar(50),Pincode int,District nchar(50));");
sc2.Connection = Co.con;
sc2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

i got error. sqlException was unhandled."There is already an object named 'IT' in the database."

how to solve this error

Comment: You already have a table named `IT` in your database. To recreate it, you first have to drop it.

Comment: table IT is not in my database.But i got this error.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a table called IT in your database. If it already exists, you cannot really create another one with same name. 
You may want to check if table exists in the database before creating it and then decide if you need to alter it or just leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the table `IT` already exists in your database, before you create it..

Your SQL query should be like..

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YourSchemaName' 
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = 'IT'))
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE IT(Name nchar(50),Phoneno int,Doorno nchar(50),Streetname nchar(50),City nchar(50),Pincode int,District nchar(50));
END
```

Comment: table IT is not in my database.But i got this error.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create a table named `IT`, which already exists in your database.

If your code should be repeatable you need to add a `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS IT;` before you're creating it again.

Also remember, that if you do it this way, all your data that may be stored in your table will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

After your comment where you say the table certainly doesn't exist in your database, I checked your connection string.
You have to add your **database name** to your connection string with `Initial Catalog=DB`.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <addname="cs1" connectionString="DataSource=SUKKOORPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName; PersistSecurityInfo=True;User ID=sa;Password=admin123"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Change *DatabaseName*  to the name of the database you want to create your table in.
Without the `Initial Catalog` set, you are trying to create a table in the *master database*.